Is there a way to change the title of graphql-strawberry python FastAPI application
I'm trying to customize the title of the GraphiQL interface in my FastAPI application.
I tried using customized html but I am not getting the similar IDE which I was having mainly the IDE which has Graphiql explorer.
Can someone please help me with this
